# Incrementing numbers with leading zeroes in awk

Tags: awk

Can we use `awk` to add `2` to every (zero padded) number, each on a line by itself, while preserving the leading zeroes?

```
0001
0002
0008
0011
0134
0146
```

The expected result is

```
0003
0004
0010
0013
0136
0148
```

My command is `awk '{print $1+2}' myfile`, but the result is

```
3
4
10
13
136
148
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can use

```
awk '{ printf "%04d\n", $1+2 }'
```

to pad to four digits, or

```
awk '{ printf "%0" length($1) "d\n", $1+2 }'
```

to pad to the length of the input number.

Comment: Another way to write your variable length example would be with the `*`. `awk '{ printf "%0*d\n", length($1), $1+2 }`